# Combine two strings into one associative array

Tags: php, string, explode

I have two strings:

```
$str1 = "type1|type2";
$str2 = "val1|val2";
```

I want to combine them into one array. The lengths of strings are dynamic, but the number of elements in both strings (elements are separated by |) will always be the same.

```
$result = [
    [
        'type' => 'type1',
        'val' => 'val1',
    ],
    [
        'type' => 'type2',
        'val' => 'val2',
    ],
];
```

The obvious solution would be `explode` the strings and loop through them.

There is probably no one step way to do this, but is there a quicker/more efficient way?

Comment: You could create an array `$str[1]` and `$str[2]`, but that just makes it easier, not faster. You could also use `map` but it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Looks like a simple "explode and tranpose" task to me. https://3v4l.org/bXVk3  I will not support the reopening of this page because it is effectively asking for multiple techniques -- all of which are easily found in web searches.

Comment: This is one way to implement the dupe target's advice: https://3v4l.org/TIaq7

Answer (score 0):

I would create a little helper function to create the result.

```
$typeString = "type1|type2";
$valString  = "val1|val2";

$result = splitTypeVal($typeString, $valString);
print_r($result);


function splitTypeVal($typeString, $valString)
{
    $results = [];
    $types  = explode("|", $typeString);
    $values = explode("|", $valString);
    $max    = max(count($types), count($values));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $results[] = [
            "type"  => $types[$i] ?? null,
            "value" => $values[$i] ?? null,
        ];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => type1
            [val] => val1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => type2
            [val] => val2
        )

)
```